# Can we run azure functions locally in VSCode without admin rights

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

Whenever I tried to debug the azure functions locally in vscode, a dialog box appears and it asks to install azure function core tools.

After installing, it throws an error as Unable to import azure.functions pylint(import-error).

When I tried to debug one more time without modifying anything, it is asking to install azure function core tools again. I don't understand why it is asking multiple times to install azure function core tools and also also why it is throwing error as could not import azure.functions. Please help on this.

I am trying the above steps as a local user. If I tried to do using admin user, it is working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try just type "func" in and see if it works (as local user). If that won't display the Azure Functions logo, try installing it manually with -g parameter:

```
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools
```

Comment: Thank you Thiago. After issuing the command in visual studio powershell, azure function core tools gets installed (as local user). Then i typed func, it is throwing the error as  **func : The term 'func' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

Comment: Then i tried to run debugger, again the dialog box comes in and asking to install azure function core tools..

Comment: try in a regular cmd rather than powershell (the func code). If that does not work, log as admin, install core tools with -g  and switch back to the local user and repeat the test.

Comment: Thank you Thiago. I installed as admin user and added the npm path to the environmental variables which fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, VSCode was trying to install Azure Functions Core Tools each time I started debugging. So installed the latest Azure Functions Core Tools **using MSI installer**.

1. I uninstalled azure-functions-core-tools from npm: `npm uninstall -g azure-functions-core-tools`. Not sure this step is 100% needed.
2. The latest Azure Functions Core Tools 3.x comes with MSI installer. Visual Studio Code debugging requires 64-bit version. [Install the Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#v2)

Comment: The msi installer just asked me for admin permissions, despite attempting to install into a user space target directory (for the v4 msi)